# Update nav menu item position programmatically

Tags: menus, navigation

I've tried adding a new programmatically on wordpress with the function:

```
 wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu, 0, array('menu-item-title' => $title,
            'menu-item-object' => 'page',
            'menu-item-object-id' => $post_id,
            'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish', // is there any 'delete', 'unpublish' ??
            'menu-item-parent-id' => $parent
        ));
```

This works when I create a page but I want to change the parent or just update the page this function adds the page again in the menu.I want to know if there is a way I can delete or update the menu item from dhe menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving menu-item-status as draft instead of publish

Comment: Please back your answers with good amount of reasons and explanations.